# Best way to store an OrderId in a cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, e-commerce

Setting up a fairly standard e-commerce site in MVC. I need to store an OrderId (basket id) in a cookie. What's the best way of doing this?

Obviously just storing the ID as plain text would be bad as anyone could change the value and mess with someone elses order.

Session isn't possible because the value needs to persist past the session expiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've decided on doing (unless someone says otherwise) is encrypting the order id for the cookie, then storing a decrypted version in the session.

I think this should give us decent enough performance while also keeping it secure.